# How can I have multiple identical backends in Spring?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I started off with a relatively simple Spring scenario where a third-party bean is created with the database details and that bean is auto-wired and used around the application using services etc which are then auto-wired into controllers.

```
WebApp  -->  Spring REST  -->  Third-Party RPC -->  Database
```

Now I have moved from each company using an instance of this to a model where I host an instance for each of them at the same time:

```
WebApp
     -->  API Management
                       -->  Spring REST  -->  Third-Party RPC -->  Database
                       -->  Spring REST  -->  Third-Party RPC -->  Database
```

In this case the API Management routes queries to the correct instance of the API (via AD groups) which means I don't require any changes to the code.

The next step would be to only have a single REST API:

```
WebApp
     -->  Spring REST
                    -->  Third-Party RPC -->  Database
                    -->  Third-Party RPC -->  Database
```

However, I'm not sure how this would work.

I know you can have multiple instance of beans using qualifiers but that wouldn't work here when you are auto-wiring single service/controllers that expect a single bean of that type.

How could I manage a scenario like this?

**EDIT:**
The number of databases can be fixed in advance and it is OK to have a restart to add a new client instead of adding them on the fly.

The number of clients is low.  Maybe 10-25. So we aren't worried about scaling issues.

Comment: The best way depends heavily of context. Are the nº of dbs fixed and preconfigured? (or are created on the fly), the number of different dbs are bounded? (or must scale to thousands), ...

Comment: Yeah this is going to be highly context dependent. I can't tell from your question if dynamic datastores or an API gateway is more appropriate, but there are enough options available given the details you shared that the only answer i could give for the question in its current form is "it depends."